# i am trying to get (productcode, productname, msrp, prieceeach) where prieceeach is less than 100 from two tables

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get (productcode, productname, msrp, prieceeach) where prieceeach is less than 100 from two tables 'products' and  'orderdetails' where priceeach is a common column and writing this code but it  is showning me priceeach of  less and more than 100

```
select p.productcode, p.productname, p.msrp, od.priceeach
from products as p 
join orderdetails as od on p.productcode = od.productcode
having p.productcode IN (select productcode 
                         from orderdetails 
                         where priceeach < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to do a subquery, just add your condition to the JOIN:

```
select p.productcode, p.productname, p.msrp, od.priceeach
from products as p 
join orderdetails as od on p.productcode = od.productcode and od.priceeach < 100
```

Your HAVING is not working because is only usefull when you have an aggregation. You could change it by WHERE or do it in the JOIN